# Últimos caracteres de uma coluna de um data.frame em R

Tags: r

Tenho uma tabela dentro de um data.frame, e preciso pegar apenas os ultimos dois caracteres dessa tabela, como faço isso?

obs.: Eu estava tentando fazer usando str_sub, porém nele eu apenas consigo definir em qual caracter começa e qual termina, e meus dados variam o tamanho de caracteres. Segue meu exemplo abaixo que não resolve:

```
base$estado <- str_sub(psd_base$itbc_name, start = 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso com `R` base é através do comando `substr`. Com ele, eu consigo extrair uma substring indicando onde ela começa e onde ela termina.

Vejamos dois exemplos práticos, com os nomes Joao e Maria:

```
Joao
1234

Maria
12345
```

Para extrair `ao` de Joao, o comando `substr` precisa extrair os caracteres 3 e 4. Para extrair `ia` de Maria, o comando `substr` precisa extrair os caracteres 4 e 5. É fácil ver que ambas as extrações começam no penúltimo caracter (`nchar(Joao) - 1`) e terminam no último caracter (`nchar(Joao)`). De modo análogo, (`nchar(Maria) - 1`) e (`nchar(Maria)`).

Automatizando isso, temos o código abaixo:

```r
x <- c("Joao", "Maria", "Pedro", "Juliana")

substr(x, start = nchar(x)-1, stop = nchar(x))
#> [1] "ao" "ia" "ro" "na"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Comment: Pronto! Obrigado pelo aviso! :)